# Stress-Strain Graph Under Uniaxial and Biaxial Strain

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, nanotechnology

I was going through a recently published journal paper by ACS (Applied Nano Materials) about gas separation using nanoporous Graphene.
DOI No. - https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acsanm.0c02340 
Supporting Information - https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acsanm.0c02340/suppl_file/an0c02340_si_001.pdf

I'm quoting the exact part where I'm facing some problems-

> Figure 2 shows the stress-calculated strain curves of graphene under
> uniaxial and biaxial strains.  [image: Mechanical response of nanoporous graphene under (a) uniaxial and (b) biaxial loadings.] Herein,
> nominal strain and stress are used, which are defined as the length
> change divided by the original length and the tensile force divided by
> the original area of cross-section, respectively (nominal thickness of
> 3.4 Å is adopted).
>
> Figure 2a shows that the mechanical responses of nanoporous graphene
> stretched along the armchair direction become distinct from that along
> the zigzag direction with the increasing strain, resulting from the
> strain-induced symmetry breaking. The strain to failure of this
> nanoporous graphene loaded along with the armchair and zigzag directions
> are 11 and 17%, respectively, which defines the maximum strains that
> can be applied to the structure. In addition to uniaxial strain, we
> also investigate the elastic responses of biaxial strain and the
> strain to failure can also exceed 10% (Figure 2b). Considering the
> structural stability based on these investigations, we explore the gas
> separation performance of nanoporous graphene under uniaxial and
> biaxial strains below 10%.

However, I understand that this is a Stress vs Strain graph. But I have some doubts regarding this -

1. What they mean by **uniaxial** and **diaxial strain**
2. What exactly they mean by **armchair direction** and **zigzag direction**
3. Lastly, it'll be very helpful for me if one can explain the graph clearly (I'm getting a vague understanding about that)

Comment: AC and ZZ: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Graphene_edge_names.svg To find the zig-zag direction find a direction where you can move in *almost* a straight line, with only a small alternating left-right-left-right zigzag motion. Perpendicular to that is the armchair direction where you have two atoms in a straight line, then a larger jump left-right, then two atoms in a straight line... It looks like hexagonal armchairs where people are seated looking alternately to the left and to the right of the direction of motion.

Comment: I've always assumed that in the honeycomb net context "uniaxial strain" is strain in either AC or ZZ direction only*but not both*, and that biaxial strain in this context means strain in both AC and ZZ directions *but not necessarily the same amount*. If it's the same in both I believe it's called "uniform strain" or "equi-biaxial strain" but I don't know for sure. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4678326/figure/f1/ In that image $Exx$ is in the AC direction and $Eyy$ is in the ZZ direction.

Comment: Thanks, @uhoh...you helped me a lot...Those answers cleared all my doubts...

Comment: That's great! But let's wait for some confirmation from others. I'm no expert in this, it's just my current understanding.

Comment: Sure!!!...but I think your understanding is right as it successfully explains the graph as well as the results...